# Can nginx re-encode XML documents, or alter XML headers?

Tags: xml, nginx, utf-8, character-encoding, iso-8859-1

I have [a problem](https://github.com/NICTA/nationalmap/issues/659) ultimately caused by a third party XML document whose actual encoding (ISO 8859-1 or Windows 1252, can't tell) doesn't match its declared encoding (UTF-8).

I'm looking for creative workarounds. We already use nginx proxies for various content, so perhaps there is a way to either:

1. Re-encode the document contents on the fly from ISO 8859-1 to UTF-8; or
2. Alter the document header on the fly, from UTF-8 to ISO 8859-1.

Are either of these possible with nginx? If not, a similar tool?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Short answer, yes it can.

```
include win-utf;
server {
  listen 5080;
  location /... {
    proxy_pass https://mapsengine.google.com;
    source_charset windows-1251;
    charset        utf-8;
  }
}
```

That is:

- `source_charset` specifies what you're converting from
- `charset` specifies what you're converting to
- and `include win-utf` brings in a file with a `charset_map` which does the conversion.

Only conversions between Windows 1251, UTF-8 and KOI8-R are supported out of the box.

More info: http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_charset_module.html