# Override incorrect declared text encoding in XML document using XMLHttpRequest

Tags: internet-explorer, character-encoding, xmlhttprequest, windows-1252

Our app is [receiving data from a source with incorrect XML headers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29958824/can-nginx-re-encode-xml-documents-or-alter-xml-headers). Although the workaround in that post works (inserting an nginx proxy), we'd like to find a client-side solution, if there is one.

So, is there a way to intercept an XML document and force the document to be interpreted as Windows 1251 rather than UTF-8? [XMLHttpRequest](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest) has an "overrideMimeType" property, but not an "overrideEncoding".

All of this matters primarily for IE, which completely fails to parse the document if it hits a single impossible character. Chrome and Firefox just show question mark characters, which is fine.

Comment: Sounds good, why not make this an answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you initially read the file with `xhr.responseType="arraybuffer"`, then blob it with your desired mime/charset like such:

```
new Blob([ arraybuff ], {type: 'application/xml;charset=windows-1251'})
```

then create a blobURL for it via `URL.createObjectURL(blob)`, and finally, xhr *that*, I think it will work.

Here's an [online test](https://googledrive.com/host/0B8BLd2qPPV7XfklTakd3aW9xUE9jX0dqQjYzT05sZTMtQldrVGswZHVJZDhvWmtUU05NOXc/xhr-change-mimecharset.html).

Comment: Wow, that's great. Thanks for putting so much effort into this!